# Can we use a timer for itself?

Tags: c++, winapi

Actually this is what i want to do;

When a condition appears, my program will close itself and after five minutes it will re-open.

Is it possible with only one .exe -by using any OS property-?

I do it with two .exe

```
if (close_condition){
     //call secondary program
     system ("secondary.exe");
     return (0);
}
```

and my secondary program just waits for five minutes and calls the primary one.

```
main (){
     Sleep (300000)//sleep for five minutes;
     system ("primary.exe");
     return (0);
}
```

i want to do it without secondary program.

(sorry for poor english)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with one application that simply has different behaviour if a switch is given (say `myapp.exe /startme`).

`system()` is a synchronous call by the way, it does only return when the command run is finished. In win32 [CreateProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) is what you are looking for.

You can also just follow Jays suggestion of letting the OS schedule your job using [NetScheduleJobAdd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370614%28VS.85%29.aspx).

But, depending on what you're trying to achieve, a better solution might be to simply hide your application for 5 minutes.

Comment: I was also about to say that: hide the application for 5 minutes and reinitalize all related variables and start over.

Comment: hiding the app isn't a solution for me, but thanks i solved it with using task scheduler

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd have to use the system task scheduler to schedule the re-launch, which in a sense is using another application, but one that is part of the OS.

I'm sure this can be done, but frankly I think you should just stick with your current setup.